# Applying style to <a href> tag placed inside C# code

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am using html code inside a .cs file to design a template for sending emails. I have added style tag to the `<a href>` tag, but it does not take effect when the email is actually sent.
Here is the code:

```
public static void Email()
{
   StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append("<a href='#' style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:inline-block;border-radius:5px;text-transform:capitalize;background-color:#208ed5;margin:0;border-color:#208ed5;border-style:solid;border-width:10px 20px' target='_blank'>");
   sb.Append("link</a>");
}
```

Comment: I think you should use double quotes after style atribute, e.g. `style = "font-family:'Helvetica Neue'; color: green; width: 100px;"`.

Comment: string formating problem

Comment: @Reddy yes string formating problem, thanks for pointing it out. I removed the single quotes arround `Helvetica Neue` and now it works fine. Thanks

Comment: @sumedha removing the quote from `Helvetica Neue` will not take this font.

Comment: @sumedha if my answer solves your problem then please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the quotes with backslash:

```
style=\"font-family:\'Helvetica Neue\',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:inline-block;border-radius:5px;text-transform:capitalize;background-color:#208ed5;margin:0;border-color:#208ed5;border-style:solid;border-width:10px 20px\"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the way you have constructed your HTML string...

In this code

`"<a href='#' style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:inline-block;border-radius:5px;text-transform:capitalize;background-color:#208ed5;margin:0;border-color:#208ed5;border-style:solid;border-width:10px 20px' target='_blank'>"`

The `style` attribute will stop here `style='font-family:'` since the single quotes which opens the style rules is closed... Hence your other rules are not even considered into this style arrtibute.

**Solution:** You really dont need to wrap the font-family values in quotes.. you can just say `style='font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`

If at all you have a font-family name with spaces in it then you have to **wrap it in quotes.**

---

**Edit 1:** If at your font-family name contains space you need to wrap them in quotes.. So you have to wrap the `Helvetica Neue` in quotes. Add a double quote and escape its meaning using backslash.. Like below..

`style='font-family:\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`

Comment: `Helvetica Neue` font will be ignored. Because font-family name with space requires quote.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Yes thanks.. I noticed that. I will update

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Updated

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, define the style in your .css file as class and assign class here in the back end. Example:

.css

```
.custom-style-a {
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
font-size:14px;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:2em;
/*rest of styles here*/
....
}
```

And the appended html will be:

```
sb.Append("<a href='#' class=' custom-style-a' .....>");
```

Advantages :

simple to implement, can easily maintain styles later. No complex formatting is required, re use the styles if necessary.

Comment: He is building a email template.. If you use class how will you render the styles ??

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes but with escaped characters, like so:

```
sb.Append("<a href=\"#\" style=\"font-family:\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:inline-block;border-radius:5px;text-transform:capitalize;background-color:#208ed5;margin:0;border-color:#208ed5;border-style:solid;border-width:10px 20px\" target=\"_blank\">");
sb.Append("link</a>");
```

Or you can always use the old way of concatenating:

```
string sb = "<a href=\"#\" style=\"font-family:\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:inline-block;border-radius:5px;text-transform:capitalize;background-color:#208ed5;margin:0;border-color:#208ed5;border-style:solid;border-width:10px 20px\" target=\"_blank\">";
sb += "link</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest single quotes inside single quotes. You are using `'Helvetica Neue'` inside `style = '... 'Helvetica Neue' ...'`. You should do it like this `style = "... 'Helvetica Neue' ..."`.`

Also I see that you are already having double quotes around the anchor element so adding directly double quotes after style will be problamatic. You'll have to use escape character `\"` instead of `"` after style as Bhojendro has explained already.